# How to move generated image file to custom directory in PHP?

Tags: php, php-5.5

I am using below PHP code to generate a new image file and transfer it to a new directory. However, when I do so I get an error saying that filename cannot be blank.

What's the error?

```
<?php
    $file = "assets/images/posts/original/2018/Dec/22/b1132bbdf75.png";
    function processjpg($filename){
        list($width,$height) = getimagesize($filename);
        $newwidth = 870;
        $newheight = 450;
        $imagetruecolor = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth,$newheight);
        $newimage = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
        imagecopyresampled($imagetruecolor,$newimage,0,0,0,0,$newwidth,$newheight,$width,$height);
        file_put_contents("/app", imagejpeg($imagetruecolor,'newjpg.jpg',100));
        echo $filename." Processed";
      };

      processjpg($file);
    exit();
?>
```

If I do not use `file_put_contents` and just use `imagejpeg($imagetruecolor,'newjpg.jpg',100)` then by default it saves in the directory where the script is executing, I want it to transfer to a custom directory.

Comment: You can add the path to the image name in `imagejpeg` function e.g: `imagejpeg($imagetruecolor,'/path/to/store/newjpg.jpg',100);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

imagejpeg() writes the file for you, you don't need file_put_contents()

```
<?php
$file = "assets/images/posts/original/2018/Dec/22/b1132bbdf75.png";
function processjpg($filename)
{
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);
    $newwidth = 870;
    $newheight = 450;
    $imagetruecolor = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
    $newimage = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
    imagecopyresampled($imagetruecolor, $newimage, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);
    imagejpeg($imagetruecolor, "/app/newjpg.jpg", 100);
    echo $filename . " Processed";
}

processjpg($file);
exit();
```

Comment: the above code works fine as i was expecting :) thanks for the update :)